# How many words are in the answer?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, anagram

There is no question. There is text:

> Ewen road worthiness

How many words are in the answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nice anagram.

> The answer is one word.

This either means that the answer is...

> one (the literal interpretation of the anagram)

or perhaps...

> two (the answer = "one word")

I don't think it is ...

> 5 - Given that "There is no question", the sentence itself is not the answer

Comment: This actually implies that the answer is seven.

Comment: @Ian I'd think it'd imply two.

Comment: @IanMacDonald It's the 5 words that are in the second line that compose the anagram. The first part is (mostly) just a comment, and partly there to fulfill the character requirement :)

Comment: Maybe you should move the first line outside the spoiler block.

Comment: @f'' I'd say no. Simply because putting the first line outside of a spoiler block will literally reveal the answer to everyone

Comment: @charfellow, you may have revealed a sentence hidden by an anagram, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Patrice But (the thing you're worried about revealing) is one of the tags in the question.

Comment: @question_asker I had considered having it outside spoilers, but thought at first (like Patrice) it might be spoilery. Given a second look at your comment though, I'm inclined to agree with you (and f").

Comment: @question_asked ok, I did NOT see it. I retract my point then :P

Answer (score 14):

It's quite obvious that

> there are two words in "the answer"

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the "anagram tag" but I agree it's quite obvious. +1

Comment: @Raystafarian dang it, I missed the anagram tag

Answer (score 13):

How many words are in the answer?

> Never mind the quoted text.
>  The answer to this question is always "one".
>  Because the answer is a number, and no number other than one is written with as many words as its value.

Comment: Or it could be "Two words", "There are four words", "There are seven words in the answer", ...

Answer (score 4):

I'm drawn to the statement:

> There is no question

That would lead me to the logical conclusion that:

> There can be no answer.

The naive interpretation would be:

> 0 - because there is no answer, so it has no words

However,

> this would be an answer and therefore imply a question - so maybe you should smile and nod and walk away rather than answer a question that doesn't exist

Comment: If you look closely at the last line or title of the puzzle, you may be able to see a question hidden amongst the letters.

Comment: There is? I see a question mark, but it can't belong to a question because the title tells me so :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on charfellow's answer

> The answer is one word.

The answer would be

> Five.

But, since

> Five is an answer as well, the answer becomes
>  "One", which can't be reduced further.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an anagram for:

> nod answer otherwise  - or - otherwise nod answer

either of which would be

> a single word "yes" for "nod" or "no" for "nod otherwise" to which I would answer "one word".

or it could be

> "zero words", since either head movement would be a gesture - no word at all.

Answer (score 1):

Others have stated that this answer is the naive interpretation which instantly lead me astray. That said, let's examine two key things you have said. You have stated:

> There is no question.

and asked

> How many words are in the answer?

From what I see, everything you say outside of those two statements is irrelevant.

> With no question, there is no answer. So, the answer is: 0.

Comment: How many teeth does a human on Mars have? There is no human on Mars, so a human on Mars has zero teeth. The moral of the story is don't go to Mars without dental insurance.

Comment: @Fax Nice argument. Just because `a x b = 0` doesn't mean both `a` and `b` are 0.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is wrong but my answer is

> 27

Because

> there are exactly 27 words in my answer if you count a number as one word.